# Grails session cannot assign java.string

Tags: grails

I'm getting this error

Error 500: Executing action [pay] of controller [org.gamestrike.PaymentController] caused exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gamestrike.PaymentController.session() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [2011-09-15] Possible solutions: getSession()
Servlet: grails
URI: /GameStrike/grails/payment/pay.dispatch
Exception Message: No signature of method: org.gamestrike.PaymentController.session() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [2011-09-15] Possible solutions: getSession() 
Caused by: No signature of method: org.gamestrike.PaymentController.session() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [2011-09-15] Possible solutions: getSession() 
Class: PaymentController 
At Line: [35] 
Code Snippet:

Comment: can you post the code snippet that is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code it's hard to tell, but it looks like you're treating `session` like a method, but it's not. It's an object - the `HttpSession` instance.

You can call the standard methods on it, e.g. `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` but Grails adds convenience behavior. It acts like a `Map` so to set or get attributes you can do this:

```
def foo = session.foo // session.getAttribute('foo')
session.bar = 123 // session..setAttribute('bar', 123)
```